# Extract second image url with imacros

Tags: javascript, regex, extract, imacros

i want to extract second image url from this:

```
<div class="product-imagebig"><img itemprop="image" src="https://example.com/300/300.jpg" xoriginal="https://example.com/700/700.jpg" id="prod-img-primary"/></div>
```

i try this but fail :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=class:product-imagebig  EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("{{!EXTRACT}}.match(/https:\/\/example.com\/700\/.*.jpg/g)")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

how to extract https://example.com/700/700.jpg with imacros?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of how you can extract the value of any arbitrary attribute from the `!EXTRACT` variable:

```
SET attrName xoriginal
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/{{attrName}}="(.+?)"/)[1];")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```